# How to resolve generic method ambiguity in C# reflection

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

I have two generic method overloads, that differ by the number of generic type parameters and argument type

```
// Argument types
public class Bar<T> {}
public class Bar<T, U> {}

// Generic method overloads
private static void Foo<T> (Bar<T> b) {}
private static void Foo<T, U> (Bar<T, U> b) {}
```

I'm assuming that i can get the method info for either one by using the appropriate number of type parameters

```
BindingFlags Flags = BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static;

// Should give Foo<int>
GetType ().GetMethod ("Foo", Flags).MakeGenericMethod (typeof(int));

// Should give Foo<int, int>
GetType ().GetMethod ("Foo", Flags | BindingFlags.Static).MakeGenericMethod (typeof(int), typeof(int));
```

However this fails with [System.Reflection.AmbiguousMatchException](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ms242316(v=vs.140)?redirectedfrom=MSDN).

I tried specifying things like `new Type[] {typeof (Bar<,>)}` as the `types` argument for some of the `GetMethod` overloads
, but the result was always null. I know i can workaround the ambiguity simply by using different names for the functions, but i'm interested to know if there's an actual solution to this.

I'm on .NET standard 2.0, .NET Core 2.0

Comment: Use [`Type.GetMethods`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.getmethods?view=netcore-3.1) instead and iterate over the results (or use a lambda) to get the `MethodInfo` instance you are wanting to use.

Comment: How would i distinguish between the two in this case?

Comment: The accepted answer suggests using just the number of generic type parameters and it works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't want to use `Type.GetMethods` and iterate over the results you can use [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.getmethod?view=netcore-2.2#System_Type_GetMethod_System_String_System_Int32_System_Reflection_BindingFlags_System_Reflection_Binder_System_Type___System_Reflection_ParameterModifier___) overload of `GetMethod` and [`Type.MakeGenericMethodParameter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.makegenericmethodparameter?view=netcore-3.1) which is available from .NET Core 2.1:

```
class MyClass
{
    // Argument types
    public class Bar<T> { }
    public class Bar<T, U> { }

    // Generic method overrides
    private static void Foo<T>(Bar<T> b) { }
    private static void Foo<T, U>(Bar<T, U> b) { }
}

typeof(MyClass)
    .GetMethod(
    "Foo",
    1,
    BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static,
    null,
    new[] { Type.MakeGenericSignatureType(typeof(MyClass.Bar<>), Type.MakeGenericMethodParameter(0)) },
    null
); // First Foo

typeof(MyClass)
    .GetMethod(
    "Foo",
    2,
    BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static,
    null,
    new[] { Type.MakeGenericSignatureType(typeof(MyClass.Bar<,>), Type.MakeGenericMethodParameter(0),Type.MakeGenericMethodParameter(1)) },
    null
); // Second Foo
```

**UPD**

Since `Type.MakeGenericMethodParameter` is not available for you the only option I see (if every method is not a part of generic class with the same generic type arguments) is to use `GetMethods` and filter the results. Simplest filter in this case would be number of generic parameters;

```
var secondMethod = typeof(MyClass).GetMethods(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static)
    .Where(mi => mi.Name == "Foo" && mi.GetGenericArguments().Length == 2)
    .First();
```

Comment: Sadly MakeGenericSignatureType is not available

Comment: Yes, missed that you are using Standard 2.0(

Comment: @MattiJokipii Then the only option is to use `GetMethods` overload and filter results. Please see the update.

Comment: Alright, thanks @Guru Stron. Seems that there is no actual solution i.e. a configuration of arguments to GetMethod that would return the correct MethodInfo.